# CSS cell no whitespace spanning entire table width

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 cell table aligned horizontally. The table has a set width, about 500px. The first and second cells are populated with string variables of varying length each time the page is loaded. What I am trying to get is no whitespace in cell 1 aligned left, and whitespace between cell 2 and the edge of the table. To look something like:

```
[[textfromvariable1][textfromvariable2                                    ]]
```

edit: eli:

it looks like this now:

```
[[text1][text2      ]
```

so cell two isnt covering the width of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've accomplished this by taking advantage of the fact that, despite setting a width in a cell, it will expand to fit its contents.

EDIT: HTML tries to give tables the width you specify for a table cell.  But a table cell will *expand* that width to fit its content.  So by starting at 1px you're telling the table to only allocate a small amount of its space to that table cell.  When it expands, it tries to take the minimal amount from other cells in order to accommodate that cell's width.  That leaves a tightly-wrapped *minwidth* cell, leaving the rest of the width to be consumed by the rest of the cells (in your example, just one other cell).

CSS:

```
.minwidth { width: 1px; }
.nowrap { white-space: nowrap; }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="minwidth nowrap">This is my first string</td>
<td>This is the rest</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I made the assumption that your 'variable1 text' shouldn't be wrapped in that first cell.  Otherwise, saying you want 'variable2' to fill is a bit arbitrary, considering you could wrap 'variable1' randomly (but on word boundaries) and achieve a smaller width.

EDIT: Here's a demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/mZCg8/

Comment: what would be the table style?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  But in your example `style="width: 500px"` I'd imagine.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about why width is 1px?

Comment: hi eli, please see my edit for what happened with the new code

Comment: They're right against each other because your table doesn't have a width.  No cell width selection will collapse the width of a table -- doesn't work that way.  Even if you said table width 500, cell 1 width 50, cell 2 width 100, it won't collapse the table width.  It will, instead, give a proportional amount of width to each cell to fill; namely, cell 2 would be 2x the width of cell 1 in the end.  Please see my edits + jsfiddle example.

Comment: Note to OP: as long as `table-layout` value is `auto` (fine here as it's the default value). Be aware that the behavior changes completely when this property is set to `fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting the width on all tds to 100% and the width of the first td to auto with a white-space property set to nowrap :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table{
                width:500px;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                border:solid 1px #ddd;
            }
            table td{
                width:100%;
                border:solid 1px #ddd;
            }
            table td:first-of-type{
                width:auto;
                white-space:nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>This is my first string</td>
                    <td>This is the rest</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Second Line : This is my first string</td>
                    <td>This is the rest</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```